Selecting specific results from multi array JSONB in MySQL
I have the following data stored in my database:
    #1   [["status", "discontinued", ""], ["profile", "strong", ""]]
    #2   [["profile", "mildly", ""], ["status", "discontinued", ""]]
    #3   [["status", "discontinued"]]

As you can see, the order can be different. Also, "profile" is not always there.
I want to select ALL items that have a "profile" with the value "strong".
Can anyone explain to me how to do it? I am unable to figure it out.
I know that profile doesn't really have a value since it is an array, but I guess we should be able to select it right?
Data is stored as jsonb in a MySQL database (latest version).
I tried this, but obviously this won't work and returns the full json.
    select article_group_extra->>'$[*]' from products;


MySQL doesn't have JSONB, that's a Postgres feature. It just has JSON.

What do you mean by "profile with the value string"? This isn't a key:value object (and why isn't it?). Do you mean element [0] is profile, and element [1] is string? Also, did you mean "strong"?

It would be much easier if you normalized instead of storing JSON. SQL's JSON functions are not very good for searching in any place.

Well, whatever way possible, I need to be able to get all products that have a
"profile" value in there. And then I need to extract the "strong" value or "mildly" value.

I see Barmar, thanks for the suggestion, will look into that!

Start with JSON_CONTAINS(article_group_extra, 'profile')

Search textual representation of your JSON value for a substring '"profile", "strong"'

Extract your array(of array) to subarrays by JSON_TABLE and check this arrays for condition 'profile' and 'strong'.
See example
SELECT id
FROM test t
where 
     ( select 1
     from JSON_TABLE(val,"$[*]" COLUMNS(Value json PATH "$")) ar1
     where 'profile' member of(value) and 'strong' member of(value)
  )=1
  ;

fiddle
